# Optimization without complex numbers

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers, radicals

We need to find a minimum of functions:

(1+$\sqrt x$)$^2$+$y^2$

Due to the fact that the function has a square root, the optimization algorithm goes into the area of complex numbers. How to make so that to receive decisions only in real numbers?

Comment: It will be difficult to help you without further information on your optimizer and the software that you are using.

Comment: Of course, I could be wrong, but it seems to me that it does not matter what algorithm we use, because the problem of minimizing functions with roots is a common problem of all optimization algorithms. In general, I use, PSO and Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a sum of two squares $(1+\sqrt{x})^2+y^2$. This sum is minimal if both terms are minimal. Hence $x = 0$ and $y=0$ will minimize the expression. The function is unbounded from the top. This means that we will not be able to give a maximal value to this equation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my question was in other thing: how to make the optimization algorithm work only with real numbers, avoiding even the slightest possibility of going into the area of complex numbers.

Comment: It depends on the optimizer that you use.

Comment: I use Particle Swarm Optimization.

Comment: Are there any tricks to avoid working with complex numbers?

Comment: The problem is that you are using a function that is not well behaved. It will always be difficult. Never used swarm optimization but you could introduce an inequality constraint e.g. $x\geq 0$ to force your optimizer to only search for positive values of $x$.

Comment: No, a simple restriction cannot be avoided, since after several cycles of calculation, the values of x will acquire an imaginary part. And you need to make it unacceptable.

Comment: It is necessary to introduce a restriction like imag(x) = 0.

Comment: @АндрейСологубов I have never seen such a constraint. You could try to use it if you optimizer allows such constraints. By writing $x\geq 0$ it should directly imply that $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as we do not have any ordering in the complex domain.

Answer (score 2):

You either use constrained optimization (optimize over $x\geq 0$) or if your solver does not support constrained optimization you can use some change of variables, such as defining $x=a^2$ and optimize over $a$ and $y$ instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mr.Löfberg. It's very helpful, like other answers in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Since we have $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=2(1+\sqrt{x})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\neq 0$$ there are no extreme points.

Comment: Wolphram Alpha say about minimum:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2Bsqrt(x))%5E2%2By%5E2+minimize

And this values must give me my optimization algorithm.